# Non-ui blocking tasks with WPF/Caliburn

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, task, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to fetch a certain amount of data from an external API and populate it within a list on a view. My setup is something like the following (excerpt):

#### ShellView

```
<xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}">
    <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" />
    ...
```

#### ShellViewModel

```
...
public bool IsBusy
{
    get { return _isBusy; }
    private set
    {
        _isBusy = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange();
    }
}

public void StartProgress()
{
    IsBusy = true;
}

public void StopProgress()
{
    IsBusy = false;
}

protected override void OnViewLoaded(object view)
{
    base.OnViewLoaded(view);
    // do some task
    ActivateItem(SomeOtherViewModel);
}
```

#### SomeOtherViewModel

```
public SomeOtherViewModel(IBusyIndicator busy)
{
  ....
}

protected override void OnViewLoaded(object view)
{
    base.OnViewLoaded(view);

    Task.Factory.StartNew(ACTION,
                    CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default)
                    .ConfigureAwait(true);
}
```

Basically, the workflow is like this:

1. Initialize `Shell`
2. *`Shell` -> OnViewLoaded*
3. Do some background work
4. Initialize `SomeOtherViewModel`
   (*gets `IBusyIndicator` injected, which is `Shell` as singleton*)
5. *`SomeOtherViewMode`l -> OnViewLoaded*
6. Do other background work, like in the example above

However when I start the application, I never see the view until everything gets loaded. Is there a way to:

- Execute an action only if everything is visible (WPF / Caliburn)
- Execute a `Task` without blocking the UI / view model updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something to happen when visibility in the UI changes then you should code that in the UI layer, either on the Loaded event or VisibilityChanged depending on your use case.

If you need it to trigger an action on the ViewModel then just reference the ViewModel from the UI. This is acceptable in MVVM.

```
public ViewModel ViewModel
{
    get
    {
        return DataContext as ViewModel;
    }
}

public void OnLoaded()
{
    ViewModel.DoThatThing();
}
```

In order to work out why your thread is blocking I would need to see a full code sample.